# Prove $\left|\frac{2a}{b} + \frac{2b}{a} \right| \ge 4$ for all nonzero $a,b$

Tags: inequality

> Prove $\left|\frac{2a}{b} + \frac{2b}{a} \right| \ge 4$ for all nonzero $a,b$

I started by squaring both sides and proving:

$(\mid\frac{2a}{b} + \frac{2b}{a} \mid)^2 \ge 4^2, \forall a,b \in \mathbb{R} - \left\{0\right\}$

My work:

Consider: $(\mid\frac{2a}{b} + \frac{2b}{a} \mid)^2$

$ = (\frac{2a}{b} + \frac{2b}{a})^2 $

$ = \frac{4a^2}{b^2} + 8 + \frac{4b^2}{a^2}$

$ = \frac{4(a^4 + b^4)}{a^2b^2} + 8$

This is where I get stuck. How do I prove:

$\frac{4(a^4 + b^4)}{a^2b^2} + 8 \ge 16$

Or I could simplify it to:

$\frac{a^2}{b^2} + \frac{b^2}{a^2} \ge 2$

But I am still not sure how to prove the above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that this is just

$$\left|\dfrac{2}{x} + 2x\right|\ge 4$$

Now squaring both sides like you suggest gives

$$\dfrac{4}{x^2}+8+4x^2\ge 16$$

$$\iff \dfrac{4}{x^2}-8+4x^2\ge 0$$

$$\iff \left(\dfrac{2}{x} - 2x\right)^2\ge 0$$

Comment: Could you please explain how:

$$\left|\dfrac{2}{x} + 2x\right|\ge 4 $$

is equivalent to:

$$\mid\frac{2a}{b} + \frac{2b}{a} \mid \ge 4$$

Comment: Let $x=a/b$ and simplify a bit

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You have to prove $\frac{a^2}{b^2}+\frac{b^2}{a^2} \ge 2$.

Consider that $(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y})^2 \ge 0$, since it is a square. This is equivalent to $x+y \ge 2\sqrt{xy}$. Put $x=\frac{a^2}{b^2}$ and $y=\frac{b^2}{a^2}$ and you get the result. [This is simply AM-GM inequality.]